# How to build a container image from scratch as a non-root user?

Tags: containers, buildah

With [buildah](https://github.com/containers/buildah) I am trying to build a container
image that should only contain the program [cowsay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowsay) and its dependencies. 
I am doing this on a [Fedora 29](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_(operating_system)) computer where I don't have root permissions. Instead of using a Dockerfile and the command `buildah build-using-dockerfile` (aka `buildah bud`) I would like to

1. Create an empty container.
2. Mount its file system.
3. Use `/usr/bin/dnf` on my host system to install packages directly into the file system under the mount point.
4. Create the container image from the file system.

The command `buildah from scratch` creates an empty container but when I try to mount the file system I get an error

```
[testuser@linux ~]$ container=$(buildah from scratch)
[testuser@linux ~]$ mnt=$(buildah mount $container)
cannot mount using driver overlay in rootless mode
ERRO[0000] exit status 1                                
[testuser@linux ~]$
```

Some more information

```
[testuser@linux ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Fedora release 29 (Twenty Nine)
[testuser@linux ~]$ buildah --version
buildah version 1.6 (image-spec 1.0.0, runtime-spec 1.0.0)
[testuser@linux ~]$
```

What goes wrong? How can I build the container image from scratch as a non-root user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short story

`buildah unshare` is needed to create an **unshare** environment. That was missing which led to the error message 
  *cannot mount using driver overlay in rootless mode* .

To build the container image create the file *build.sh* with this content

```
container=$(buildah from scratch)                                                                                                                                                                       
mnt=$(buildah mount $container)                                                                                                                                                                         
LC_ALL=C dnf install --installroot $mnt --release 29 --setopt=install_weak_deps=False -q -y cowsay                                                                                                      
LC_ALL=C dnf --installroot $mnt clean all                                                                                                                                                               
buildah umount $container                                                                                                                                                                               
buildah commit $container cowsay-container1
```

Then run the script *build.sh* inside an **unshare** environment

```
[testuser@linux ~]$ buildah unshare bash build.sh
```

List all images to see the newly built container image

```
[testuser@linux ~]$ buildah images                                                                                                                                                                     
IMAGE NAME                                               IMAGE TAG            IMAGE ID             CREATED AT             SIZE                                                                          
localhost/cowsay-container1                              latest               9d9b88a8d5f1         Feb 18, 2019 17:26     307 MB                                                                        
[testuser@linux ~]$
```

To try out the the newly built container image run

```
[testuser@linux ~]$ podman run localhost/cowsay-container1 cowsay hello                                                                                                                                
 _______                                                                                                                                                                                                
< hello >                                                                                                                                                                                               
 -------                                                                                                                                                                                                
        \   ^__^                                                                                                                                                                                        
         \  (oo)\_______                                                                                                                                                                                
            (__)\       )\/\                                                                                                                                                                            
                ||----w |                                                                                                                                                                               
                ||     ||                                                                                                                                                                               
[testuser@linux ~]$
```

The *build.sh* script could be improved by adding some `buildah config` commands to provide some metadata information (e.g. `buildah config --created-by` and `buildah config --cmd`).

## Longer story

Instead of building the container image with the script *build.sh*, it is also possible to step into the **unshare** environment and run build commands manually.

```
[testuser@linux ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Fedora release 29 (Twenty Nine)
[testuser@linux ~]$ buildah unshare
[root@linux ~]# container=$(buildah from scratch)
[root@linux ~]# mnt=$(buildah mount $container)
[root@linux ~]# LC_ALL=C dnf install --installroot $mnt --release 29 --setopt=install_weak_deps=False -q -y cowsay
warning: /home/testuser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/cc67b957fb78eebe6a861a8b69ef4728d0660a636645813224b6ba94fbc80ce0/merged/var/cache/dnf/updates-0b4cc238d1aa4ffe/packages/bash-4.4.23-6.fc29.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 429476b4: NOKEY
Importing GPG key 0x429476B4:
 Userid     : "Fedora 29 (29) <fedora-29@fedoraproject.org>"
 Fingerprint: 5A03 B4DD 8254 ECA0 2FDA 1637 A20A A56B 4294 76B4
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-29-x86_64
[root@linux ~]# LC_ALL=C dnf --installroot $mnt clean all
33 files removed
[root@linux ~]# buildah umount $container
020ee8e3fb29274a306c441770d2458c732e84076cc0487ce6ea06ac957640d4
[root@linux ~]# buildah commit $container cowsay-container2
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob b3fbecd80150: 292.45 MiB / 292.45 MiB [========================] 2s
Copying config 8aa2ad2933ce: 263 B / 263 B [================================] 0s
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
8aa2ad2933ce33c8ed8b7551c4a3261177ebd811c9b813b40d5ea77536ac6ef5
[root@linux ~]# exit
exit
[testuser@linux ~]$ buildah images
IMAGE NAME                                               IMAGE TAG            IMAGE ID             CREATED AT             SIZE
localhost/cowsay-container1                              latest               9d9b88a8d5f1         Feb 18, 2019 17:26     307 MB
localhost/cowsay-container2                              latest               8aa2ad2933ce         Feb 18, 2019 17:47     307 MB
[testuser@linux ~]$ podman run localhost/cowsay-container2 cowsay hello
 _______
< hello >
 -------
    \   ^__^
     \  (oo)\_______
    (__)\       )\/\
        ||----w |
        ||     ||
[testuser@linux ~]$
```